# How to change map zoomlevel on buttonclick without using dijit?

Tags: javascript, function, button, buttonclick, arcgis-js-api

I am working with the esri javascript API to create a webmap. I want to have a button next to the map to allow me to zoom-in/out (not the standard esri button). Now, I found a lot of examples doing this using dijit (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_navigation.html) but I just want to use a simple html button like:   Zoom in and then in the script part say something like:

function zoomin(){map.setZoom()}

Now my problem is that I don't know how to make that work. I guess the problem is that after the buttonclick it can't find the zoomin function since it's inside the require([...]),function(){} But I can't put it outside neither since the code depends on the require.

So, it would be great if you could tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For zooming in on the map, use the setZoom method incrementing the current zoom level to zoom in and decreasing to zoom out.  For example:

```
//zoom out:
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);

//zoom in:
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
```

As an example, using the sandbox of the Esri sample above:
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=toolbar_navigation

...replace line 85 to 91 with this:

```
      registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function () {
        //navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
      });

      registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function () {
        //navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);
      });
```

This will allow the Zoom In and Zoom Out buttons to control the map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No I don't really think that's what I'm looking for. My navigation toolbar looks like that:  
<div id="navToolbar">
      <button type="button" onclick="zoomin()" ><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></button> 
</div>
So I don't have all the dojo-buttons etc.
So I need to replace the registry part I guess but it's not working for me

Comment: Oh, I got it working. Just needed to change the registry.byId to document.getElementbyId(...).onclick = zoomin; 
And then it's working
Thanks